# How to synch the following scenario?

Tags: c, winapi, synchronization

I've tried several ways to synch the following scenario.  The last way I tried is to use an event to signal after FifoQueueData();.  Thread 2 would then release from the event and send the data over the network.  The problem is that thread 1 loops around too fast and signals the event before Thread 2 waits on that same event.  This causes the event to wait until it times out.

```
thread1 {
  for(1 .. 10) {
    GenerateData();
    FifoQueueData();
  }
  signal();
}

thread2 {
  while(not signalled) {
    WaitForQueuedData();
    FifoDequeueData();
    SendDataOverNetwork();
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally, queues inherently sync, as do events. But you are missing information. Please provide full information what you have done and a [mcve], including types. As described, you have a race-condition which should not occur if using the communication mechanisms you mention (queue, event). But perhaps you mean something differnt by these names.

Comment: Automatic reset events were invented for scenarios like this one. As always, @Olaf thinks he knows, but doesn't. This is getting tedious. Seriously. If you don't want this kid to down-vote, close-vote, or comment on your questions, use the [tag:c++] tag instead of the [tag:c] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are on Windows, you could indeed use the thread message queue for synchronization (this particular queue is threadsafe, maybe message queues are what Olaf means by "normally").  To do that, use `GetMessage` and `PostThreadMessage`.

Be aware, however, that message queues are accessible from other code -- for type safety, you might put objects in your own queue, and use the thread message queue only for waking the other thread.  (To see why this is important, read about "window shatter attacks").  In that case, you might as well just be using auto-reset events.

Answer (score 0):

> The last way I tried is to use an event to signal after FifoQueueData();. Thread 2 would then release from the event and send the data over the network. The problem is that thread 1 loops around too fast and signals the event before Thread 2 waits on that same event. This causes the event to wait until it times out.

If you are going to use events, use 2 manual-reset events and a thread-safe lock, like a critical section.  One event signals when the queue has space available, and one event signals when the queue has data.  Thread1 would wait for the Available event to be signaled, lock the queue, put data into it, set the Data event, and reset the Available event if the queue is full, before finally unlocking the queue.  Thread2 would wait for the Data event, lock the queue, dequeue an item, set the Available event, and reset the Data event if the queue is empty, before finally unlocking the queue and processing the item.

```
CRITICAL_SECTION csQueue;
HANDLE hAvailableEvent, hDataEvent;
BOOL bFinished;

...

InitializeCriticalSection(&csQueue);
hAvailableEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);
hDataEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
bFinished = FALSE;

...

void FifoQueueData(BOOL IsFinished)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hAvailableEvent, INFINITE);
    EnterCriticalSection(&csQueuelock);
    if (IsFinished)
        bFinished = TRUE;
    else
    {
        // put data in the queue 
        if (queue is full)
            ResetEvent(hAvailableEvent);
    }
    SetEvent(hDataEvent);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&csQueuelock);
}

BOOL FifoDequeueData()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hDataEvent, INFINITE);
    EnterCriticalSection(&csQueuelock);
    if ((queue is empty) && (bFinished))
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&csQueuelock);
        return FALSE;
    }
    // remove data from the queue 
    SetEvent(hAvailableEvent);
    if (queue is empty)
        ResetEvent(hDataEvent);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&csQueuelock);
}

thread1
{
    bFinished = FALSE;
    for(1 .. 10)
    {
        GenerateData();
        FifoQueueData(FALSE);
    }
    FifoQueueData(TRUE);
}

thread2
{
    while (FifoDequeueData())
        SendDataOverNetwork();
}
```

Another option is to use an [I/O Completion Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx). Call [`CreateIoCompletionPort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862.aspx) before starting the threads, then have Thread1 queue data using [`PostQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458.aspx) and Thread2 dequeue data using [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986.aspx). IOCP uses a FIFO queue and is self-syncing.

```
HANDLE hQueue;

...

hQueue = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1);

...

void FifoQueueData(BOOL IsFinished)
{
    if (IsFinished)
        PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hQueue, 0, 1, NULL);
    else
    {
        LPBYTE buffer = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, size of data);
        if (buffer)
        {
            // copy data into buffer...
            if (!PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hQueue, size of data, 0, (LPOVERLAPPED)buffer))
                LocalFree(buffer);
        }
    }
}

BOOL FifoDequeueData()
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    ULONG_PTR ulCompletionKey = 0;
    LPBYTE buffer;

    if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hQueue, &dwSize, &ulCompletionKey, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&buffer, INFINITE))
        return FALSE;

    if (ulCompletionKey == 1)
        return FALSE;

    // copy data from buffer up to dwSize bytes as needed...
    LocalFree(buffer);

    return TRUE;
}

thread1
{
    for(1 .. 10)
    {
        GenerateData();
        FifoQueueData(FALSE);
    }
    FifoQueueData(TRUE);
}

thread2
{
    while (FifoDequeueData())
        SendDataOverNetwork();
}
```

Comment: By using manual-reset events, you risk a race condition, but the critical section prevents it.  Spurious wakes aren't the end of the world, if you include logic to handle them (you haven't).  Starvation is a more serious problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It was just an example to introduce a concept, not to be a be-all-do-all solution, Obviously, the OP needs to learn more about how to implement various multi-threaded data sharing models in general.